# NetSuite Saved Search formula to filter for Opps remaining at a stage for over 60 days

Tags: sql, netsuite

Need a saved search that shows Stalled Opps that haven't changed sales stage in over 60 days. I'm new to Netsuite Sales Admin (previously Salesforce Admin).. and cannot figure out the formula to count days since stage change.

Formula(Date)

--- I know i need to use System Notes to determine when Stage was set and then count 60 days but am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula.  You'll want to group the results by opportunity and status and take the minimum of `{today} - to_date({systemnotes.date})` because you'll get multiple system notes matches per opportunity.

```
case 
  when {entitystatus} = {systemnotes.newvalue} and {today} - to_date({systemnotes.date}) > 60 then 1 
  else 0 
end
```

equal to 1

Comment: Thank you- this didn't work for me though. it returns a message saying i have syntax error:  
 
Your formula has an error in it. It could resolve to the wrong datatype, use an unknown function, or have a syntax error. Please go back, correct the formula, and re-submit.

Search: Opportunity Search
Formula: CASE when {entitystatus} = {systemnotes.newvalue} and {today} - to_date({systemnotes.date}) > 60 then 1 else 0 end

Comment: The field type needs to be Formula(Numeric).  Other than that, this search works in my account.  Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/QGW3sh8) with the configuration.

Comment: Fantastic! thank you-- it worked. Even our consultant couldn't figure it out.  I appreciate you!

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to comment on the above but not enough rep yet. NetSuite formulas don't allow you to have line breaks. `case when {entitystatus} = {systemnotes.newvalue} and {today} - to_date({systemnotes.date}) > 60 then 1 else 0 end` should work.

Comment: thanks-- should that be a formula(date) format or should i be using a different format (text or  numeric)?

Comment: I would use numeric since it seems you are evaluating to either a 1 or a 0 by your "then" and "else" statements. You would only use date if your result needed to be in date format.